# Purging whole CVS repository

Tags: cvs

We have got a CVS repository of 10+ years of codebase. We are considering to purge the repository and get rid of the history before 2010.

For this when, I am trying the following command on my CVS NT Server in my CVSROOT directory

```
D:\cvsroot\MyModule>cvs admin -o D:\cvsroot\MyModule ::MyTag2010 .
```

I am getting the following error.

```
cvs admin: in directory .:
cvs [admin aborted]: CVS directory without administration files present.  Cannot continue until this directory is deleted or renamed.
```

After searching on the internet, I found that I had to run this command on a place other than the CVS module directory. For this I created a new directory `BlankModule` and tried to run the command on this new folder.

```
D:\cvsroot\BlankModule>cvs admin -o D:\cvsroot\MyModule::MyTag2010 .
```

I am getting the following error

```
cvs admin: Administrating .
cvs admin: in directory .:
cvs [admin aborted]: there is no version here; do 'cvs checkout' first
```

I have two questions

1. The CVS purging mechanism should work on the CVS Server. Why would I need to checkout a snapshot of MyModule to run this command?
2. Where am I going wrong to achieve my goal of purging the CVS repository?